# How to update Sharepoint2010 list Item using android?

Tags: android, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm developing a sharepoint2010 app for android. I want to update sharepoint 2010 `ListItem` using code below:

```
private void updateListItem() {

    String serviceUrl = "http://IP_address/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ((AbstractHttpClient) httpclient).getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm",
            new NTLMSchemeFactory());
    NTCredentials creds = new NTCredentials("username", "password", "55",
            "demo");
    ((AbstractHttpClient) httpclient).getCredentialsProvider()
            .setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);
    try {
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpclient.getParams(),
                120000);

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serviceUrl);
        StringEntity se;            
        String str1 ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope      xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body>"
                 + "<UpdateListItems xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\">"
                 + "<listName>"
                 + "{DF1398C7-EF73-485E-913E-5F5896D6DF22}"
                 + "</listName>"
                 + "<updates>"
                 + "<Batch OnError='Continue' ListVersion='1'>"
                 + "<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>"
                 + "<Field Name='Title'>View</Field>"
                 + "<Field Name='Resource'>7;#A Kr Singh</Field>"
                 + "<Field Name='Project'>13;#Microsoft- SharePoint based Employee Portal</Field>"
                 + "<Field Name='Task'>1;#Accounting</Field>"
                 + "<Field Name='Date'>2014-11-21 11:15:50</Field>"
                 + "</Method>"
                 + "</Batch>"
                 + "</updates>"
                 + "</UpdateListItems>"
                 + "</soap:Body>" + "</soap:Envelope>";
        se = new StringEntity(String.format(str1, HTTP.UTF_8));

        se.setContentType("text/xml");
        httppost.setEntity(se);

        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        InputStream in = httpresponse.getEntity().getContent();
        String str = inputStreamToString(in).toString();

        readSoap(str);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But getting error

> soap:ServerException of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.0x8102006d

Please give me any solution.
Or give me any other way to update `SharepointListItem` using android.

Comment: That's a very generic error when using services. what are you currently using for development?

Comment: I am using android environment for mobile app,and back-end is made in .net.

Comment: Hi @AsshwaniSingh I'm developing a new service to do NTLM authentication https://www.nafiux.com/wasp/ if I can help you please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Hi after that some reteaches,I found the solution when adding below action in request header.

httppost.setHeader("SOAPAction",
                    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems");
and after that working fine.